# D3: change html in transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

In this (broken) minimal example, I want the text to fade out, change while invisible, and reappear with the changed content. This should be simple (no cross-fading), but the error message complains that `.html` is not a function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Image mask</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js">
</script>
<body>
</body>
<script>
var textbox = d3.select('body').append('div');

textbox
 .html('Click me.')
 .style('cursor','pointer');

var i = 0;
textbox.on('click', function() {
 i++;
 textbox.transition()
  .style('opacity', 0)
 .transition().duration(300)
 .html('Click me. <strong>' + i + '</strong>')
 .transition().transition()
  .style('opacity', 1);
});
</script>
```

PS I found an example for [cross-fading](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f7dcecb19c4af317e464), but it seems unnecessary complicated (since I don't want cross-fading) and requires version 4's `.active` method.

**Update.** It "works" if `.html` is replaced with `.text`, but I really need the content to be parsed.

Comment: And .html is not a function for transition. Change to .text

Comment: Isn't quite simple to use jQuery.animate()?. Both (D3 & jQuery) can coexist without problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out (as you've discovered) that `d3.transition` doesn't have a `.html()` method. This is confirmed by the lack of `transition.html` in the [docs here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md#transitions). That's not totally unexpected, considering that there is no obvious way to interpret what it means to do a continuous transition of the `innerHtml` value, but then again `.remove()` **is** "transitionable", in the same way you would want `.html()` to be transitioned (i.e. non-continuously, right at the end of the transition).

Oh well. You can still do what you want to do by essentially subscribing to the end of the transition, using the `.each("end", function() {})` mechanism:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Image mask</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js">
</script>
<body>
</body>
<script>
var textbox = d3.select('body').append('div');

textbox
  .html('Click me.')
  .style('cursor','pointer');

var i = 0;
textbox.on('click', function() {
  i++;
  textbox.transition()
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .each("end", function() {
      d3.select(this)
        .html('Click me. <strong>' + i + '</strong>')
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 1);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I found a way to do this with `setTimeout`, but your method looks cleaner

Comment: @bongbang: Awesome... Happy to help. Why not accept the answer then?

Comment: I was trying to make sure that the solution really works for me (it apparently does, fingers crossed). By the way, why `.transition().transition()`?

Comment: My bad. Should be a single call to transition. Also, hope it didn't come off as too agro to ask for accepting the answer. Just that it happens every so often that folks to do that, and since I've been trying to go on somewhat of a points spree, I got worried.