# Wrapping long labels with axis transition in D3.js v4

Tags: d3.js

This is the original example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321.

I added transition to the x-axis and made two fiddles to demonstrate the fact that wrapping long labels on an axis with transition works in version 3 but doesn't work in version 4 of D3.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .transition()
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll(".tick text")
//  .call(wrap, x.rangeBand()); (v3)
    .call(wrap, x.bandwidth());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cfwbh0st/
https://jsfiddle.net/Ls5ux9gv/

How do I go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the middle of rewriting your logic when I found out the root cause of your problem. By calling `.transition()`, you change the object from a selection to a transition object. But transition objects [don't have a `.html()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38023307/5015356). You didn't recognise that because you use `.call()`. That is executed *before* the transition has completed, however, and thus the ticks are overwritten with the default behaviour. I'll pose two solutions below. The first is an adaptation of your code, the second is the code I was working on. Hopefully it will give you some more pointers.

**As close to your code as possible**

```js
var margin = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(.1)
    .paddingOuter(.3);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(8, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/7555321/raw/1b17baa35f75336a8d9f4c8292b1d1ab850f3d86/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", x(data[0].name))
      .attr("y", -26)
      .text("Why Are We Leaving Facebook?");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .transition()
      .call(xAxis)
      .on("end", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .selectAll(".tick text")
            .call(wrap, x.bandwidth())
      });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
});

function wrap(textElements, width) {
  textElements.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.title {
  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 80,
    right: 180,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 180
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(.1)
  .paddingOuter(.3);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(8, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/7555321/raw/1b17baa35f75336a8d9f4c8292b1d1ab850f3d86/data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", x(data[0].name))
    .attr("y", -26)
    .text("Why Are We Leaving Facebook?");

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .transition()
    .call(xAxis)
    .on("end", function() {
      d3.select(this).selectAll(".tick text")
        .call(wrap, x.bandwidth())
    });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.name);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.value);
    });
});

function wrap(textElements, width) {
  textElements.each(function() {
    d3.select(this).html(function(text) {
      var words = text.split(/\s+/),
        word,
        lines = [],
        currentLine = '',
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1
      while (word = words.shift()) {
        if (getTextWidth(currentLine + word, "10px sans-serif") < width) {
          // We're safe to add the word
          currentLine += word + ' ';
        } else {
          // If we add the word, we exceed the line length
          // Trim to remove the last space
          lines.push('<tspan x="0" y="9" dy="' + (++lineNumber * lineHeight) + 'em">' + currentLine.trim() + '</tspan>')
          currentLine = word + ' ';
        }
      }

      lines.push('<tspan x="0" y="9" dy="' + (++lineNumber * lineHeight) + 'em">' + currentLine.trim() + '</tspan>')
      return lines.join('');
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Measure the width of a text were it to be rendered using a given font.
 *
 * @param {string} text the text to be measured
 * @param {string} font a valid css font value
 *
 * @returns {number} the width of the rendered text in pixels.
 */
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
  const element = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = element.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;

  return context.measureText(text).width;
};

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.title {
  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, even with [your solution](https://jsfiddle.net/m3ud8kg0/) the animation is still jerky, i.e. you can see a flash of unwrapped labels before they get wrapped. I think I may have found a solution in the meantime, but haven't yet implemented it, namely [this](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/05/09/building-a-better-d3-axis.html). The so called _decorate pattern_ looks promising.